# How to account fro newline char when checking strings against eachother

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to detect whether two strings appear in the same text file which contains on name per line. When there is only 1 line per text file it works fine however when the newline char \n is added it can't recognise it.

```
def move_offline(self):
    with open("publicusr.txt", "r") as onlst:
        onl_list = []
        for line in onlst:
            onl_list.append(line)

    with open("user.txt", "r") as single:
        singusr = single.readlines()

    if str(singusr) in str(onl_list):
        print ("Match")
```

If I put

```
if str(singusr)+"\n" in str(onl_list):
            print ("Match")
```

I don't get an error however nor does the program do anything else of note.

Comment: You should `strip` your strings of extreaneaous white-space.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you for your suggestion it doesn't seem to work though, I changed the variable to the stripped version however i had to do str(list in question).strip since list doesn't have a strip method. Maybe this is why it didn't work.

Comment: No, you need to `strip` the strings *inside the list* not the result of `str(thelist)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Worked perfectly string does not contain \n anymore. Thank you.